# Page scrolling "disabled" because of Google Map

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have navigation bar on my site, and a Google Map below it, in a div that is 100% wide.
When the visitor comes to the page and tries to scroll down, instead of scrolling down, Google map zooms out, so i guess the focus is on the map/div element where the map is.
Can anyone help and throw me some code snippet to fix this?
A lot of users dont even know that there is something bellow the map, since they cant scroll properly.
Here is a code:

```
<body onload="initialize()">

    <header>
        <div class="wrap clearfix">

            <h1 class="logo"><a href="#" title=""><img src="assets/images/txt/logo.png"/></a></h1>
        </div>


        <nav class="main-nav" role="navigation">

            <ul class="wrap">
                <li><a href="#" title="Home">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="About">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="Bio">Bio</a></li>
            </ul>

        </nav>

    </header>

  <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>

  <div class="main" role="main">

  Some webpage content here

  </div>
```

Comment: But what if someone *wants* to zoom the map?

Comment: I guess they can click on it and then zoom? But, by default, the page itself could scroll, not the Google Map

Answer (score 2):

When initialising the map you can set an option to disable zooming when the mouse wheel is used.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions

See the 'scrollwheel' option.

Answer (score 0):

Your options are:

1. Make the map smaller so they won't always have the map over it.
2. Put some sort of invisible dom element over the map so their cursor won't be interacting with the map. (this disables scrolling zooming, etc on the map) Something like:

HTML

```
<div class="overlay"></div>
```

CSS

```
.overlay {
height:100%;
width:100%;
position:absolute;
top:0px; /*adjust to move it down */
}
```

Comment: Homepage always have the huge map over it, and this "problem" only happens there. I dont know anything about jQuery/JS, but i was thinking this would be pretty simple to do with some simple code snippet :\

Comment: If you just want to display the map with no interaction, all you need is html & css. Answer updated with code

Answer (score 0):

Here is the detailed procedure. Make sure to edit your Javascript file and that it can be accessed in your browser! (/js/mycode.js). Just edit the HTML file, copy and paste (no need to edit the JS).

HTML (/map.html):

```
<head>
   <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
   <script src="/js/mycode.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="map-canvas" style="height:400px;"></div>
</body>
```

Javascript (/js/mycode.js): (**Just copy and paste!**)

```
if ($('#map-canvas').length) {
        var map,
            service;

        jQuery(function($) {
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(26.13485, -73.87206);
                var myOptions = {
                    zoom: 16,
                    center: latlng,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                    scrollwheel: false
                };

                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), myOptions);


                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: latlng,
                    map: map
                });
                marker.setMap(map);


                $('a[href="#google-map-tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function(e) {
                    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
                    map.setCenter(latlng);
                });
            });
        });
    }
```

Now edit the style, latitude and longitude and other maps parameters. And here you go!